# ReactJS lifecycle setState in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components for demonstration of my problem:

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, Row } from "react-flexbox-grid";
import Hello from "./Hello";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Michal"
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "Tina" });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    console.log("App componentDidUpdate", prevState, this.state);
  }

  handleUpdate = value => {
    console.log("App handleUpdate");
    this.setState({ name: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Hello name={this.state.name} update={this.handleUpdate} />
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Child:

```
import * as React from "react";

class Hello extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    // setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.update("Matus");
    // }, 0);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log("Hello componentDidUpdate", prevProps, this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>;
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

In child component I want to set value in parent state via props function. But setState function is ignored, it works if props function is called from setTimeout.

Can you explain me why it work in setTimeout, why I should avoid this construction. And what is correct way to do it?

Hello component represent "Select", which in componentDidMount will fetch options and set default value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Components initialise from the bottom up in React. So in your example `Hello` triggers `componentDidMount`, attempts to set the state in App via `this.props.update`, then `App` overrides it a split-second later when it calls its own `componentDidMount`. The name you set in the child component never reaches the state.

I'm not sure what the purpose of this is, hopefully only for leaning purposes as components shouldn't need to immediately set their own state when mounting. If you need to perform some logic before initialising the state in `App` you can use a `constructor` and do it there.

Regardless, the solution is remove the initial state setter in `App`.

Comment: In demo I initialize state in constructor (what is useless - there is value what I don't need, in my real solution it is undefined) and rewrite in componentDidMount with correct values. But yes as you wrote I should set correct value in constructor and remove componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1):

It is not ignored and it does fire. You are just not observing it with your logs.
Check out:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-jackson-b2r2b?file=/src/App.js

In the console you will see the following execution order in the console window:

```
Hello componentDidMount props = Object {name: "Michal", update: function ()}
App handleUpdate value =  Matus 
App componentDidMount props = Object {}
Hello componentDidUpdate props = Object {name: "Tina", update: function ()}
App componentDidUpdate state = Object {}
Object {name: "Tina"}
```

Thus you will see the child `componentDidMount` fires and completes mount before the parent component completed and fires its `componentDidMount`, as components completes mounting from the child components up.

So you just never observe the state going to Matus because it triggers a new state change to Tina when it completes mounting.

Answer (score 1):

You `setState` function from Hello component is ignored because of the React lifecycle. Basically App `componentDidMount` function overrides your state change from Hello component before it was rendered. That's why `setTimeout` helps, it moves your state change to the new rendering loop.

I don't know exact why you are trying to load data and pass it from the child component to parent but the good practice in React is to pass data from top to bottom. So the better solution would be to use `Select` component to just render the data from parent and react to user events.

```
<Select options={options} selected={option} handle={handleSelect} />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

- React rendering is synchronous.
- Rendering is a depth-first traversal

Now,

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.props.update("Matus");
    }
```

Is executed first, which sets the name **Matus**. Then the following executes -

```
componentDidMount = () => { this.setState({ name: "Tina" }); };
```

This sets the name **Tina**.

All of this happens on the first call-stack where the rendering happens. If we use *setTimeout()*, then

```
this.props.update("Matus");
```

will be moved to the second call-stack, which will be executed after the initial rendering and mounting has ended, thus setting the name **Tina** and triggering a re-render.

Comment: I understand why with setTimeout it updates parent state to 'Matus', but I didn't understand why without setTimeout I can't see that parent state wasn't set to 'Matus' and replaced with 'Tina'. I can see in console log componentDidUpdate is updated once.

Comment: componentDidMount() of child is executed before componentDidMount() of the parent (You can see here- https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sun-oby1o?file=/src/App.js ). Without setTimeout(), child component sets name to Tina but parent overrides it to Matus.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use class components, you need to use a constructor function to initialise state and pass the props from parent to child.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Michal"
    };
  }

  // ... rest of parent component
```

```
import * as React from "react";

class Hello extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.update("Matus");
    // }, 0);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log("Hello componentDidUpdate", prevProps, this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>;
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

Comment: Initializing state should happen in constructor, but they want to update the state on mount, which is a slight difference and not the cause of the problem.
Passing data only in one direction from parents to child is the part of your solution that might actually help, but the other answers describe the reasons to a better extent.

Comment: The important part of my answer is not the parent constructor, but the child constructor. the ```this.props.update``` call in componentDidMount won't work since this.props does not exist in a class component until being initialised in the constructor by calling ```super(props)```

Comment: The important part is that you removed the state update in the parent componentDidMount. You could've kept the initialization via class properties and it would work nonetheless. Your solution is working and is the proper way, but the explanation doesn't go into any detail why the original scenario didn't work. That's just what I would improve in your answer, but I'm not the OP anyways.